# My character goes blind

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am level 48 and after a few in-game hours, my character goes completely blind! I can still see the compass bar and the cursor, I can do shouts, attack, etc. However, all I can see is pure darkness.

It happens as if you transforming back from or to werewolf form. So, the vision goes blurry for a split second, and before you know it, it fades into complete darkness.

I have tried loading from another file, a different character, I have tried uninstalling the game, removing all mods and ESP files from the data folder, re-installing, but nothing helps...

Anyone had this issue before?

Comment: Maybe a problem with the game-loading? It happens sometimes with me for Runescape.

Comment: looks an actaull in-game effect to my character though :S as if its a spell of some sort. and i can get rid of it :S

Comment: how did you get rid of it?

Comment: Does the in-game statistics screen show your character as having any diseases or anything?

Comment: sorry, i meant to say ''i cant''.
@JamesGecko - all the active effects i have are ressistance to disease, warrior stone (increases damage), Dibella (speech craft).
that about it. :S

Comment: Are you using any mods? And have you defeated Alduin? http://steamcommunity.com/app/72850/discussions/0/828927580796788544/

Comment: @Lyrion i HAD mods, but i got rid of them, deleted the ESP files, unsubscribed on steam, uninstalled the game, then installed it without mods. and still got the problem.
As for Alduins Wall, thats the weird thing.. i can no longer continue on that quest. :S its disapeareed as a quest to be completed. And i certainly have not even faced him to battle yet :S

Comment: @user53220 Hmm, i'm thinking that this is not good, I mean you can't even finish your main questing line. Does it always happen at the same time? Or is it after you start playing at a certain hour? I mean if you can play for an hour then save, can you reset the blind timer? And have you tried on a different character if it happens there aswell?

Comment: @Lyrion yeah, i just tried with a different character, level 28. no problem... its only with my main character... i seriously cannot be bothered doing it all again with my level 28 lol. with my main character, (i finally decided to join the stormcloaks as i was sitting on the fence with the civil war) i am upto the part where i have to take ulfrics war axe to the jaarl in whiterun. So, Ulfric gives me the war axe, i fast travel to whiterun and i go blind as soon as i get there... so i tried just waiting there with the ''T'' command for 24hrs.. and still, i go blind

Comment: @Lyrion Also, whats the ''light mods'' that the users speak of in that link you posted? i havent tried your method though. i try it soon and see how we go.

Comment: @user53220 Probably something like the Ultimate Lighting Mod or Realistic Lighting Mod. From what i've read he also had a blessing that ran out just at the moment he went blind. Are you using any blessings? Or do you have a blessing soon to run out?

Comment: Cant you go back one save or two saves? And then take another route or Quest and see what happens...

Comment: If you had mods before, they probably left something in your save file. That's pretty common, and fits your report that it doesn't happen with other saves.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend trying the following:

- Reinstall all mods that could be even remotely related (if you have any)
- Just wait a few minutes. The game could resolve it by itself
- Look for a mod on the Nexus to patch it
- A fresh save. I know you're level 48, but it might be worth creating a new save just to test if it's a problem with the save or with your game
- Make your own mod with the Creation Kit. The game engine uses several classes of effects when performing an action like turning you into a werewolf. I would look for the MagicEffect involved and disabling any particle effects or visual effects inside

If none of these work, then I don't know what will.

Answer (score -1):

*COMPANIONS QUESTLINE SPOILERS*

If you've just become a werewolf from the Companions questline, it's normal. Just let it stay. It usually wakes you up after 30-60 seconds in the middle of nowhere.

Answer (score -3):

If your using mods you might have read the Elder Scroll and the game glitches out on you. I've seen some mods do this to people, I think its part of the mod.